Fabric.js with Vue 3 - Can not load svg image
I am trying to use Fabric.js ^6.3.0 with Vue 3 to load a svg image to canvas:
<script setup lang="ts">
import * as fabric from 'fabric'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const fabricCanvas = ref()
onMounted(() => {
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(fabricCanvas.value)
  fabric.loadSVGFromURL('./assets/roof.svg', (objects, options) => {
    const svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options)
    canvas.add(svg)
    canvas.renderAll()
  })
})
</script>

<template>
    <canvas ref="fabricCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</template>


Nothing happens, svg is not loaded into canvas. But this code works well if I use Jquery with Fabric.js 5.3.0
In this line const svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options), I got an typescript error with objects: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FabricObject<Partial, SerializedObjectProps, ObjectEvents>[]'
Have you ever tried Vue 3 with Fabric? Please help me!

Had the same issue. I found a solution.
Based on official description: https://fabricjs.com/api/functions/loadsvgfromurl/
The 2nd parameter for loadSVGFromURL now gets "original svg element and the generated FabricObject as arguments". So you have the use the 2nd argument, just as it is!
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svgFile, (_orig, converted) => {
  this.canvas.add(converted);
  this.canvas.renderAll();
});

